# Tree diagram using tikz in latex. How do I make the different forest classes to be on two or three columns?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

This is the code I have:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
     % \tikzset{
    basic/.style  = {draw, text width=3cm, align=center, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
    root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=green!30},
    onode/.style = {basic, thin, rounded corners=2pt, align=center, fill=green!60,text width=3cm,},
    tnode/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=15em, align=center},
    xnode/.style = {basic, thin, rounded corners=2pt, align=center, fill=blue!20,text width=5cm,},
    wnode/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!10!blue!80!red!10, text width=6.5em},
    edge from parent/.style={draw=black, edge from parent fork right}

} %

\begin{forest} for tree={
    grow=east,
    growth parent anchor=west,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},->, >={latex}] 
         (!u.parent anchor) -- +(10pt,0pt) |-  (.child anchor) 
         \forestoption{edge label};} } % lsep is used for arrow distance [Spatial Models, basic,  l sep=10mm,
    [Discrete Patches\\ AI, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
        ]
    [Continuous, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
        ] 
    [Intervention, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
       ] ]       \end{forest} 

\begin{forest} for tree={
    grow=east,
    growth parent anchor=west,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},->, >={latex}] 
         (!u.parent anchor) -- +(10pt,0pt) |-  (.child anchor) 
         \forestoption{edge label};} } % lsep is used for arrow distance [Equation types, basic,  l sep=10mm,
    [ODEs, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
        ]
    [PDEs, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
        ]
    [Integral Equation, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
        ] 
    [Fractional Differential Equation, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
       ] ]       \end{forest}

\begin{forest} for tree={
    grow=east,
    growth parent anchor=west,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
    edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},->, >={latex}] 
         (!u.parent anchor) -- +(10pt,0pt) |-  (.child anchor) 
         \forestoption{edge label};} } % lsep is used for arrow distance [Intervention models, basic,  l sep=10mm,
    [Mechanical interventions, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
        ]
    [Treatment, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
        ]
    [Educational, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
        ] 
    [Multiple intervention, xnode,  l sep=10mm,
       ] ]       \end{forest}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please extend your code to a full ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. That way other users can just copy and paste your code. More users will be willing to help when there is a MWE.

Comment: Welcome. // You may find this checklist helpful to add what's missing and remove what's not really needed to show your problem so it's much easier for us to help you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790